# How to retrieve data from multiple tables from an Oracle database, create a DataTable and then store this data in a class object in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, join, datatable

I am trying to retrieve data from multiple tables from an Oracle database using C#. I use `while (reader.Read())` to get all the records from a table. However, this time I want to get only one specific record and store it in an object of class called production. I have the following code:

```
public DataTable GetProduction(string serialNr)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string queryString = "SELECT E.SERIENR, R.PRODUCT_ID, R.LIJNSOORT, R.RATIO, R.AANTAL_PLAKKEN, R.EXTRA_INFO_ALFANUMERIEK_1, H.LAMELHOOGTE, R.LAMELAANTAL " +
                    "FROM RO_EXEMPLAAR E JOIN " +
                    "RO_ROOSTER R ON E.PRODUCT_ID = R.PRODUCT_ID JOIN " +
                    "RO_LAMELHOOGTE H ON H.LIJNSOORT = R.LIJNSOORT AND H.RATIO = R.RATIO " +
                    "WHERE E.SERIENR=" + serialNr;
                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(queryString);
                try
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    connection.Open();
                    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
                    da.Fill(dataTable);
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            return dataTable;
        }
```

When I execute this by giving a serial number, it is giving me the error:

> ORA-00904: invalid identifier

I checked the sql statement and it seems all correct to me. How can I solve this issue?

I also want to create a production object using the data stored in this `DataTable`. How is this possible? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: *"giving me the error saying that the identifier is invalid"* - Please [edit] your question with the *exact* error message (use the "`> `" prefix on a separate paragraph to differentiate it from other paragraphs). The exact wording will indicate which identifier is invalid and (by way of phrasing) what's reporting the error. Right now, there's not enough information to help you.

Comment: @madreflection I just edited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle Database, SQL Update statement will not work (OLEDB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902859/oracle-database-sql-update-statement-will-not-work-oledb)  It's using `OleDb` instead of `Oracle` but the issue is the same: you're not quoting the value so it's interpreting it as an identifier, which is not found. You need to pass that as a parameter instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: @madreflection using the Oracle SQL developer query tool I realized that it does not allow using + in the middle of the query. I tried by passing an exact serial nr in the query and it works. But now, I need to make it in such a way that I can pass any serial number into query.